# classes under lib folder are not detected in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, production-environment, ruby-on-rails-2

In my project, I have written few classes under lib folder but rails is not detecting those classes in production environment. I get the uninitalized Constant error.

I use Apache in the production environment and rails script/server in the development environment.

Is anything wrong with RAILS_ROOT environment? Can anyone suggest how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Rails, but you achieve that in Ruby by this: (it will work in rails too, but rails must be having some elegant way)

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "lib",'your_module_name')
include your_module_name
```

Try this in `config/application.rb` (I assume you have rails3)

```
config.load_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )
```

Update: Rails - [why would a model inside RAILS_ROOT/lib not be available in production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872450/rails-why-would-a-model-inside-rails-root-lib-not-be-available-in-production-mo)

Comment: actually i am facing this problem only in production environment, its working fine in development env , any reason for this

Comment: that's weird. lib classes are autoloaded in Rails2.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the name of your file matches the name of the class or module defined in it, accounting for any directories.

ie:

```
lib/my_new_class.rb

class MyNewClass
end
```

Or if you have a directory hierarchy:

```
lib/my_files/my_module.rb

module MyFiles
  module MyModule
  end
end
```