# Rails lib class not being loaded in production, works ok in dev

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jruby

I have a class in the lib directory: lib\db_cache.rb, that defines class DbCache.

My Rails model can access it when in dev mode and also when I run rails console in production mode.

But when I run the production mode rails server, the model class, eg Foo, complains about "uninitialized constant" Foo::DbCache,

```
org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2677:in `const_missing', 
org/jruby/RubyMethod.java:134:in `call'
```

I have this line in application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```

I have also tried the other variations shown in the linked SO questions - but no joy.

I am using jruby 1.7.3 (1.9.3p385) - Java 1.7.0_13-b20, on linux.  Rails is version 3.2.12.

I've seen these questions [Rails - why would a model inside RAILS_ROOT/lib not be available in production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872450/rails-why-would-a-model-inside-rails-root-lib-not-be-available-in-production-m) and [Best way to load module/class from lib folder in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3) but that doesnt seem to help my case.

Thanks in advance for any ideas on this.

PS My work-hack-around for now is to require 'db_cache' in my model class :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to related to enabling config.threadsafe! in /config/environments/production.rb

This is what I had:

```
  # Enable threaded mode
  if defined?(Rails::Server)
    puts "Rails Server running - so enable threadsafe!"
    config.threadsafe!
  end
```

As I am using jruby, I dont believe this is so much of an issue.  At least, when I removed these lines, things worked much better :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to extend a class.  Without seeing the db_cache.rb file I can't know for sure.

If that is the case it is perfectly fine to have

```
extend DbCache
```

in your model class definition